Why the ui image on a ui panel is not covering 100% the whole game view screen?
there is a slight gap around the game view window.
this screenshot show the canvas settings

and this screenshot show the ui panel settings

in the last screenshot i resized part of the game view window to show the small gap i mean:
i resized it on the right to see it better.


Im not sure how you think that last picture is explainatory, maybe if you had drawn some arrows and put words on it it might. But it just looks like a covered up picture - give you seem to cover up other things, it doesnt help.  Looking at the black area in your scene view, the words are at a distantce from the edge, this seems inline with the scene view.. So it looks OK from that point of view.

Its probably the sprite you are using for the panel.  Try setting the sprite to null.

probably the square sprite which has rounded corners, use some editing tool to create your own square sprite

You don't need a square sprite. Leaving it empty causes the colour to fill to the edges by default.

The Image component has a sprite called Background in the "Source Image" field. That sprite has a transparent and rounded border on it. Remove that sprite and you will get an untextured image that fills the bounds of the panel.
